# What counter balances gravity here?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force, string

[image]Lets consider a stone tied to one end of a massless and unstretchable string... Now if i'll start rotating, it will form a conical pendulum & then the equilibrium is achived when the pendulum attains horizontal circular motion.... Now to maintain that state we give a constant force to string.... Here, which force counterbalances gravity? Is it the torque due to applied force cancels out the torque due to gravity?

The angle θ changes from 0 to 90°

Comment: You have it all in the force diagram. Remember to split forces into components.

Comment: There definitely are torques, but torque is not an important property based on your question about the forces.  You need to understand forces first.

Answer (score 1):

The vertical component of the Tension balances the weight of the body or as you say the force due to gravity.
The horizontal component of the Tension is unbalanced  and it produces the centripetal acceleration.
$$T\cos(\theta)=mg$$
$$T\sin(\theta)=m\dfrac{v^2}{r}$$
You can solve these equations.
By the way,  the angle $\theta$ never changes because $L$, $h$, $r$ are all the same

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible for a conical pendulum to be horizontal as there is no force countering gravity. Hence the semi-vertical angle will **tend to 90** if the string is spun fast enough but the vertical component of the tension will be balancing the the weight of the object